# C++ copy-on-write substring/subarray

Tags: c++, slice, copy-on-write

I have a lot of text processing (e.g. xml, json, yaml) and I'd like all the parsed sub-strings to refer to the input buffer, rather than copying.

I'm somewhat influenced by Golang's slices, which all have optimal size (ptr+len). Since we don't really have a GC in C++, probably copy-on-write and refcounts make a more appropriate design.

Optinally, I'd to abstract away also static c-strings under the same string/slice class.

Is there one solution that provide all of:

1. Avoid copying when taking substrings.
2. Copies-on-write when writing.
3. Wraps static c-strings with the same class.
4. Not OS/compiler specific (i.e. gcc's std::string won't work).

If not, what else should I consider when implementing this? (I'm thinking of using atomic ops to manage refcounts, and marking c-strings with a null refcount).

EDIT:

- std::string_view is no good since it doesn't provide requirement 2.
- Specific scenario: I'd like parse a json document without creating many sub-string copies. Then I'd like to change only one string value.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe stlab libraries have a wrapper class for [copy-on-write](https://github.com/stlab/libraries/blob/develop/stlab/copy_on_write.hpp) funcionality.

However, you might be interested in just going with `std::string` for writing and [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) (C++17) for reading, since they are standard. Performing a copy is a matter of making a new `std::string`, meanwhile copying a `std::string_view` will only copy it's description (base pointer and size).

For reference counting, there's [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

Comment: Thanks @jorge-bellón , however I'm looking for a something that would give me both write operations (string) and zero-copy (string_view) together. AFAIK the standard library doesn't provide this.